# Is it possible to create a set of wallets with mutual trustlines for an asset that I issue?

Tags: assets, wallets, federation, token-wallet

I thought that Federations in Stellar might address this situation, but the more I'm reading, the less sure I am.  I'd like to know if it's possible to do the following with Stellar:

1. Create an asset
2. Create a set of wallets with trustlines to each other to trade this asset
3. Allow users of these wallets to create a username and password to access their wallets
4. All while keeping these users' ability to freely trade this and other assets onthe DEX?

The goal, as you probably guessed, is to have a custom asset built on Stellar that has the least friction possible for trading between other users within the custom asset's ecosystem.

Can this be done?  Or would users of this custom asset be forced to work with Public/Private IDs and creating their own trustlines?